# Start function with both mousewheel and click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.div').bind('mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
```

How do I write if I also want a single click to start the function? I want the user to be able to choose himself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make the function separate and bind both to it!

```
function magicFunction(e, delta) {
  etc...
}

$('.div').bind('mousewheel', magicFunction).bind('click', magicFunction);
```

Answer (score -1):

**You mentioned that you would want them to both to perform the same event, but wanted the user have the ability to choose, the following would work:** (*It uses a checkbox to control, which event is fired*)

```
//Event Binding
$('.div').bind('click', doWork).bind('mousewheel', doWorkWheel);

//Wheel Function
function doWorkWheel(e, delta) 
{
    if($('#checked').prop('checked'))
    {
        doWork();
    }
}

//Click Function
function doWork(e, delta) 
{
    alert('Fired');
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/Gr2Nz/1/)